# Url management - .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I recently published my first website so i am new to web design.

That being said, I was trying to manipulate my webpages urls hoping to make them "pretty". Since my website is very small, visitors don't need to know the full url of the page they are viewing so I was trying to replace the "www.domain.com/folder/file.php" format with "www.domain.com" only **without redirecting the user to the index page**.
I read around that you are supposed to do it with the .htaccess file in your root directory but I could not figure it out.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to your vague description: no, that's not possible. URL mapping cannot completely hide request paths. That can only be had with wrapping everything into a frame/set.

Comment: Thanks! 
Sorry if my description wasn't very accurate, i will try to provide more information next time!